# Running the contributed command:'extension.openWithDefault' failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, default-browser

It has worked before.

I don't know what is s the problem now, but now I just can't use this command, I have to choose `openWith`, then select the browser after.

Is this problem occurred for someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [“Open in Browser”](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser) and press "Ctrl+B".

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Debian Stretch with Gnome 3, solved it by adding
`"open-in-browser.default": "firefox"` to user settings.
Make sure "firefox" is added to your path or replace with your browser choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you install "open in browser", you can click the 'File' then 'Preferences' and 'settings',then search 'open in browser',Set default browser to 'chrome',hope my answer can solve this problem